# Table View is not showing the values

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift

i want to assign value to array and show that values in table view.. 
i am getting the values through webservice using webservice code.
the values are getting perfectly, i use print statement for testing it shows perfectly that values. but when i assign that values to table view it shows nothing. here is my code. please help me out

```
let con = "http://192.168.10.10/Hand.svc/";
var list = [String]()
var answer:String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: con+"getlocation?email=saim@gmail.com")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                    let asd = myJson.value(forKey: "getlocationResult")
                    self.answer = String(describing: asd!)
                    var mystring =  self.answer.components(separatedBy:"=")
                       let size = mystring.count
                    var i = 0
                    while (i < size-1 )
                    {
                        let st1 = mystring[i+1]
                         self.list = st1.components(separatedBy: ";")
                        print (self.list[0])
                        i += 1
                    }


                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }

    }
    task.resume()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return(list.count)
}


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
        return(cell)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related but `return` is not a function (no parentheses) for example `return cell`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DispatchQueue.main.async` - for update the UI why because network call is background queue .

```
 do {
     let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
       let asd = myJson.value(forKey: "getlocationResult")
       self.answer = String(describing: asd!)
       var mystring =  self.answer.components(separatedBy:"=")
       let size = mystring.count
        var i = 0
       while (i < size-1 )
         {
            let st1 = mystring[i+1]
            self.list = st1.components(separatedBy: ";")
            print (self.list[0])
            i += 1
           }
         DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            self.yourTableViewName.reloadData()  
          })
   }
   catch
   {
   }
```

vadian comment ;

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return list.count 
}


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: self.tableView.reloadData() ... it's not accessing

Comment: what is your table view name

Comment: so it's mean i have to make outlet of tableview ?

Comment: `self.list = st1.components(separatedBy: ";") ` only assign last one

Comment: @HassanShahid Consider to use a more suitable format than CSV or whatever your composed string contains. You are assigning (overwriting) rather than appending in each loop iteration the components to `self.list` so of course only the last value remains.

Comment: @NazmulHasan in print statement it shows all the values.

Comment: @HassanShahid `self.list = st1.components(separatedBy: ";")` only assign last one . trust me .. for loop to your `list` after while loop . hope you will see only one that is last

Comment: @NazmulHasan your method is very helpful thanks... it will help further in my webservice.thanks :)